# How to convert a string array with dates like 20.02.2017 to yyyyMMdd format in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I have an array list which contains string like the below

17.2.2017
28.2.2017
1.3.2017

I would like to convert this to yyyyMMdd format so that i can compare these dates against the current date. I have tried using ParseExact but it didn't work.

`

Comment: You'll usually get better answers if you paste exactly what you *did*, and exactly what *happened* (including error messages), rather than just saying "it didn't work".

Comment: FWIW, it's not clear whether you're starting with a string that contains multiple dates; an array of strings that contain multiple dates; an array of strings, each of which contains a single date; an arraylist of strings, each of which contains multiple dates; or an arraylist of strings, each of which contains a single date. Including code like `$dates="17.2.2017", "28.2.2017", "11.03.2017"` would remove all doubt, and lead to answers that actually *answer* the question, rather than just getting close to the answer.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' have edited my question with the code and a screenshot of the excel

Comment: Think about what someone who might want to help might have to do to run your code. They'd have to create an Excel workbook, enter data by hand, set up the date format, etc. Think about providing just an ArrayList of dates instead of all the other stuff. Also, FWIW, the question as it stands now is quite different from the first version.

Comment: Not very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#you can format string to date like this
[DateTime]::ParseExact("17.2.2017", 'd.M.yyyy', $null)

#for your string with all dates
$dates="17.2.2017 28.2.2017 11.03.2017"
-split $dates | %{[System.DateTime]::ParseExact($_, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could depend on your locale, but start with something like:

```
$d,$m,$y = "28.2.2017" -split "\."
$date = [DateTime]::Parse($("{0}/{1}/{2}" -f $m, $d, $y))
$date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Adjust as needed to consume your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$a ="17.2.2017 28.2.2017 1.3.2017"
$a -split ' ' | % {$b = $_ -split '\.'; Get-Date -Day $b[0] -Month $b[1] -Year $b[2]}
```

If you've got an array of dates you just remove the first split :

```
$a ="17.2.2017","28.2.2017","1.3.2017"
$a | % {$b = $_ -split '\.'; Get-Date -Day $b[0] -Month $b[1] -Year $b[2]}
```

Just for one date :

```
$a ="17.2.2017"
$b = $a -split '\.'
$date = Get-Date -Day $b[0] -Month $b[1] -Year $b[2]}
$sate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i do the same if all my dates are stored in an array say $AllDates and i would like to put them in yyyymmdd format ex: 20170217.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the challenge ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$d,$m,$y='28.2.2017'.split('.')
'0'*(4-$y.length)+$y+'0'*(2-$m.length)+$m+'0'*(2-$d.length)+$d
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did & it works.

`$Date1 = -split $Date | %{[System.DateTime]::ParseExact($_, 'd.M.yyyy', $null)}
 $Date2 = $Date1.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`